# Doing math in with find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Strangely, I can do this:

```
previous_post_position = @post.position - 1
previous_post = Post.find_by(position: previous_post_position)
```

But not this:

```
previous_post = Post.find_by(position: @post.position - 1)
```

How to do math correctly with the `find_by`?

(Position is an integer)

Comment: *Why* can't you use the second version? Do you get an error, an unexpected result, etc?

Comment: Is the `previous_post = Post.find_by...` embedded within some block apart from `previous_post_position = ...`?

Comment: I would like to see the output.

Answer (score 1):

The both versions are correct. If you have the wrong result it has nothing to do with the syntax of *find_by*.